# Plain query in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection called `constructora` that has the following structure:

```
{
    "_id" : A,
    "edificio" : [
        {
            "_id": X,
            "a" : 48,
            "b" : 59  
        },
        {
            "_id": Y,
            "a" : 8,
            "b" : 5  
        },
        {
            "_id": Z,
            "a" : 0,
            "b" : -1  
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

So, I want to make a query that returns, for each sub document (*edificio*) his parent's *_id*. An example:

```
{
    "_id" : X,
    "a" : 48,
    "b" : 59
    "id_constructora" : A
}
{
    "_id" : Y,
    "a" : 8,
    "b" : 5
    "id_constructora" : A
}
{
    "_id" : Z,
    "a" : 0,
    "b" : -1
    "id_constructora" : A
}
```

How can I do that?

### EDIT

Now I'm trying using aggregate, and grouping my query by "edificio_id", so for each document in edificio I can get my desired output:

```
db.constructora.aggregate(
    [
        { $project : { "_id" : 1, "edificio._id" : 1 } },
        { $group : { _id : "$edificio._id" } }
    ]
).pretty();
```

But it doesn't work. The output is:

```
...
{
    "_id" : [
        ObjectId("613339376430333562373466"),
        ObjectId("663736363935393066656236"),
        ObjectId("313933613036363364633832"),
        ObjectId("653135313831633638336436")
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : [
        ObjectId("643531326231663739626465"),
        ObjectId("343231386237333365356461"),
        ObjectId("373461303864636138393263"),
        ObjectId("386433623966653737343962"),
        ObjectId("303863633366376431363335"),
        ObjectId("663833343161643639376161"),
        ObjectId("383833363836663532633733"),
        ObjectId("396330313961353137333166"),
        ObjectId("646535366662363364613837"),
        ObjectId("633937613032656436653965")
    ]
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest taking a first attempt at it. Probably want to look into the aggregation framework as a starting point.

Comment: @DavidMakogon David, I've tried grouping by 'edificio._id' with db.constructora.aggregate([{$project:{"_id":1, "edificio._id":1}},{$group: {_id:"$edificio._id"}}]).pretty();  but it doesn't work :(, can you help me to find the solution?

Comment: Tomi - first thing you need to do is *edit your question* with the query you tried. As posted, it's very difficult to read. Also, the comment area isn't the place to bury further info. When you do edit your question, please also include any details about output, errors, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$unwind` to break the embedded array into embedded docs, `$addFields` to rename and add the `_id` into the embedded doc followed by `$replaceRoot` to promote the embedded document to the top level in 3.4 mongo server.

```
db.constructora.aggregate([
   {$unwind:"$edificio"},
   {$addFields:{"edificio.id_constructora":"$_id"}},
   {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$edificio"}}
])
```

More info here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/#replaceroot-with-an-array-element